# multiple divs open accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have modified the jquery accordion to show more than one opened divs like this:

```
$(function() {
        var icons = {
            header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
            headerSelected: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
        };
        jQuery('#accordion').accordion({
             icons: icons,
             collapsible: true,
             active: false,
             autoHeight: false,
             navigation: true, 
             disabled: true });

            jQuery('#accordion h3.ui-accordion-header').click(function() {
                jQuery(this).next().slideToggle();
            });

    });
```

It works fine except one thing that when I click any header, It expands but arrow on header doesn't change.

I followed following link:

http://sammybrent.inelsternwick.com/blog/?p=30

Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you're trying to mimic the accordion-behaviour. But on a click, that's not everything the accordion does. It changes the classes of the arrow and the headers too, which changes the picture.

So what you could do to get the arrows right is to change the class from ui-icon-circle-arrow-e to ui-icon-circle-arrow-s and vice versa if the header is clicked. Adding something like:

```
$(this).find('.ui-icon').toggleClass('ui-icon-circle-arrow-e ui-icon-circle-arrow-s');
```

would work I guess. I don't think using the accordion like this is a very good solution btw.

Comment: It worked but one problem is that ui-icon-circle-arrow-e is not default icon when accordion is linked or shrinked.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. But I guess these are side-effects from mimicing an accordion.

Comment: Should I add multiple accordions, If so How can I because that will also mess the Jquery code